# String Events vs Class Events in L5.2, which is better?

Tags: laravel, events

According to the [L5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events), Events/Listener pairs are created via classes. But after some quick experimenting, I found you can also use strings and skip the Event class entirely making it easier to make, less prone to errors (since there's no Event class to create), and more descriptive.

**EventServiceProvider**

```
// Class
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\MyEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\MyListener',
    ],
];

... becomes ...

// String
// Replace App\Events\MyEvent with a string which describes your event
protected $listen = [
    'eventaction' => [
        'App\Listeners\MyListener',
    ],
];
```

Using the string version above means that the File `App\Events\MyEvent` does not need to be created. That's one less file to worry about and having a string for the event instead of a class makes it easier to remember.

**App\Listeners\MyListener**

```
// Class
public function handle(MyEvent $event)
{
    // Do something
}

... becomes ...

// String
// Remove the data type in $event so it'll accept a string
public function handle($event)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Fire the event the same way you would a class only this time use the string label.

```
event('eventaction', [$event]);
```

My question is are there specific instances where a class should be used while on other instances a string could be used? What added benefit does the use of Event classes (`MyEvent`) have over string events?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know of any specific event where you would have to use a class.  Classes just make it a little bit easier to contain certain logic.  You can also use the constructor to inject additional dependencies into the event classes as well.  They are really just there to contain any methods/data which would ultimately be required by any listeners.

Keep in mind one event can have many listeners each of which might require different data from the event class.  So if you are firing the event a lot, it would be easier to contain all that within in a class rather than doing something like...

```
event('logout', [$param, $otherParam, $otherOtherParam]);
```

If you ever add another listener which requires yet another parameter from the event, then you need to go through all your code to add the additional parameter where if you use a class, you only need to change it one place which would be inside that class.